# What is the following derivative: $\frac{d^k}{dx^k} x^n$

Tags: calculus

I believe it will be of the form $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots$ (with a string of $k$ terms) multiplied by $x^{n-k}$ but I can't understand how to find the length of this string.

Comment: Do it for small values of $k$, then find a pattern and attempt induction. For example, how many terms in the string when $k=1$? How many when $k=2$?

Comment: The third in the string should be $n-2$.  You can express the result using factorials.

Answer (score 1):

If you claim that the number of factors is $k$ (as it is, since you derive $x^n$ $k$ times) then the coefficient is simply $n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)$. In this way
$$
\frac{d^k}{dx^k}(x^n)=n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)x^{n-k},
$$
for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $0\leq k\leq n$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$${d^k\over dx^k}x^n={n!\over (n-k)!}x^{n-k}=k!\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}$$